# Wordpress: Php im calling the post, how can i make after 3 post it will make a new Li and inside it the next post will be there

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm new using php and I'm confused with this one; the code below is a team slider.  Inside the `ul` it has one `li` with 3 divs inside (3 divs means 3 people ) Can you check my code below and enhance it. I'm confused with this one, I don't know how to do it. My code below is only adding new div(people). How can I make this possible after 3 divs it will make another li and inside it's the new batch of people,

The code below is calling the category team and it can call 9 items, I want to achieve after 3 item (Div) it will make another li so inside it the another 3 will go there.

```
          <div class="team-wrapper">
            <div id="teamSlider">
              <ul class="slides">
                <li>


                  <?php
                  $args = array(
                    'category_name' => 'team',
                     'post_type' => 'post',
                     'posts_per_page' => 9,
                     'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
                     );
                  query_posts($args);
                  $x = 0;
                  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>       
                  <div class="col-md-4 wp5">
                    <img src="<?php the_field( 'Team_img' ); ?>" alt="Team Member">
                    <h2><?php the_field( 'Team_name' ); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_field( 'Description' ); ?></p>
                    <div class="social">
                      <ul class="social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'link1' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'link2' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'link3' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <?php if ($x == 2) { echo ''; $x = -1; } $x++; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

                </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
```

**Note: I'm using this template: http://tympanus.net/Freebies/HalcyonDaysTemplate/ You can download it here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/07/14/freebie-halcyon-days-one-page-website-template/ you can check the WE'RE A TEAM THAT ADORE WHAT WE DO section**

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try this:

```
<div class="team-wrapper">
    <div id="teamSlider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <?php
                query_posts(array(
                    'category_name' => 'team',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 9,
                    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
                ));
                $x = 1;
                while (have_posts()) :
                    the_post();
                    if ($x == 1) :
            ?>       
            <li>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="col-md-4 wp5">
                    <img src="<?php the_field( 'Team_img' ); ?>" alt="Team Member">
                    <h2><?php the_field( 'Team_name' ); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_field( 'Description' ); ?></p>
                    <div class="social">
                        <ul class="social-buttons">
                            <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'link1' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'link2' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'link3' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
                if ($x == 3) :
                    $x = 1;
            ?>
            </li>
            <?php
                  endif;
                  $x++;
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: error             <?php
                query_posts(array(
                    'category_name' => 'team',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 9,
                    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
                ));
                $x = 1;
                while (have_posts()) :
                    the_post();
                    if ($x == 1) :
            ?>       
            <li>

Answer (score 0):

As per the html i can see in the link you shared, there **needs to be a li created for each item within ul**. The 3 items logic will be taken care of by the javascript driving that plugin.

For getting one li per item, you need to loop it outside li rather than inside li as is the case currently.

**Updated Code:**

```
<div class="team-wrapper">
            <div id="teamSlider">
              <ul class="slides">


<?php
                  $args = array(
                    'category_name' => 'team',
                     'post_type' => 'post',
                     'posts_per_page' => 9,
                     'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
                     );
                  query_posts($args);
                  while(have_posts()){ ?>   

                <li>



                  <div class="col-md-4 wp5">
                    <img src="<?php the_field( 'Team_img' ); ?>" alt="Team Member">
                    <h2><?php the_field( 'Team_name' ); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_field( 'Description' ); ?></p>
                    <div class="social">
                      <ul class="social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'link1' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'link2' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'link3' ); ?>" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </li>
<?php } ?>
                </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
```